# Django Error 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django

```
The website was running without any problem. I recently updated **wcgi.py** and **production.py**, and now I get a 500 error. Here's the detailed response:

********************************************************************************
>Error 500: Internal Server Error

>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

>Error message: (none)

Some possible causes of this could be: 

1. The script/program that was executed contains errors or the permissions for the script are not properly set.

2. The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
********************************************************************************

**wsgi.py:**
********************************************************************************
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from sys import path

SITE_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
path.append(SITE_ROOT)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxx.settings.production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
********************************************************************************
```

**base.py**
    ********************************************************************************
    """Common settings and globals. .... base.py"""

```
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath
from sys import path


########## PATH CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)

path.append(DJANGO_ROOT)
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION


########## DEBUG CONFIGURATION
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
########## END DEBUG CONFIGURATION


########## MANAGER CONFIGURATION
ADMINS = (
    ('xxx xxx', 'xxx@xxx'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS
########## END MANAGER CONFIGURATION


########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## GENERAL CONFIGURATION
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
########## END GENERAL CONFIGURATION


########## MEDIA CONFIGURATION
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'media'))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
########## END MEDIA CONFIGURATION


########## STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (`enter code here`
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
########## END STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION


########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
SECRET_KEY = r"-40hhv97se0m46r@bv!6&b!l76a#-%(26=z^hcjra!2-z$q#sr"
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION


########## SITE CONFIGURATION
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
########## END SITE CONFIGURATION


########## FIXTURE CONFIGURATION
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'fixtures')),
)
########## END FIXTURE CONFIGURATION


########## TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates')),
)
########## END TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION


########## MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Default Django middleware.
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'tools.UserBasedExceptionMiddleware',
)
########## END MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION


########## URL CONFIGURATION
ROOT_URLCONF = '%s.urls' % SITE_NAME
########## END URL CONFIGURATION


########## APP CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    # 'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin panel and documentation:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
########## END APP CONFIGURATION


########## LOGGING CONFIGURATION
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'applogfile': {
            'level':'ERROR',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'APPNAME.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15, # 15MB
            'backupCount': 10,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'APPNAME': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    }
}
########## END LOGGING CONFIGURATION


########## WSGI CONFIGURATION
WSGI_APPLICATION = '%s.wsgi.application' % SITE_NAME
########## END WSGI CONFIGURATION


########## SOUTH CONFIGURATION
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    # Database migration helpers:
    'south',
)
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
########## END SOUTH CONFIGURATION
********************************************************************************
```

**production.py**
    ********************************************************************************
    """Production settings and globals."""

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from os import environ

from .base import *

from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


def get_env_setting(setting):
    """ Get the environment setting or return exception """
    try:
        return environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

########## HOST CONFIGURATION
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [xxx.xxx.xxx]
########## END HOST CONFIGURATION

########## EMAIL CONFIGURATION
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'xxx@xxx')

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '')

EMAIL_HOST_USER = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER', '')

EMAIL_PORT = environ.get('EMAIL_PORT', 25)

EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[%s] ' % SITE_NAME

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
########## END EMAIL CONFIGURATION

########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
DATABASES = {}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## CACHE CONFIGURATION
CACHES = {}
########## END CACHE CONFIGURATION


########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
SECRET_KEY = get_env_setting('SECRET_KEY')
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION
********************************************************************************
```

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the updated part of wcgi.py and production.py. Also it would be helpful if you share the whole traceback of this error with us.

Comment: I updated my question with wsgi and production settings (import some settings of the base.py). The project runs well for local testing, but it does not in production stage. I don't know how to get the traceback of this error in production stage. Can you please let me know how to get that?

Comment: Just turn on `settings.DEBUG` in production to get the traceback.

Comment: I turned on DEBUG as follows:

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

Still get the same response. Where am I supposed to find the traceback in production?